# PowerShell networkswitchmanager cmdlet to manage switches

Tags: powershell, switching

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/networkswitchmanager/?view=win10-ps) cmdlet to supposedly connect to switches to get and set options. I haven't found much info on how this connects except for [this](https://ss64.com/ps/new-cimsession.html) page that requires the CimSession to be set. I'm not sure if this via SNMP or SSH, since I don't see any of those parameters in the list. All I see is to connect to a computer, not an actual switch.

Comment: Protocol type appears to be DCOM or WSMAN.

Comment: Maybe check out [PowerShell Remoting Over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7).

Comment: It has to be a supported switch. You’ll create a cimsession to it and use that. Check this https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Admins-can-plug-into-network-switches-with-new-PowerShell-module?amp=1

Comment: @DougMaurer We have some old 4800 series Avaya switches. Don't think it is supported, but what would I need to search for? DCOM, WSMAN or WinRM?

Comment: Find out from Avaya if they support [OMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Management_Infrastructure)
"To manage devices with the NetworkSwitchManager PowerShell module, the switches need to support being managed with OMI via PowerShell; check with the switch vendor on this."